# Number Pyramid in JS

Tags: javascript

So I was tasked with making this and I was able to fing a way to make it work as intended. I was wondering if there is a simpler way to get this same result?

```js
function generatePyramid() {
    var totalNumberofRows = 10;
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 1; i < totalNumberofRows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            output += i;
        }
        console.log(output);
        output = '';
    }
}
generatePyramid();
```

Answer (score 6):

Your function is pretty straightforward and achieves the result, but there are a few improvements you may consider.

Here are are some common language-agnostic generalizations and best practices for writing functions.

1. Separate [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) like prints from the core algorithm logic. Prefer returning results, which makes the code reusable by giving the caller control to decide whether to `console.log` the result, write it to file or perform further transformations on the return value.
2. Avoid [hardcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) literal numbers like 10 into a function. This could easily be a parameter, which is like a knob that controls the function's behavior and lets you use it for many more purposes. For example, if the user of the function wanted a pyramid with 5 rows, they need only call `generatePyramid(5)` instead of `generatePyramid(9)`.

   `totalNumberofRows` is slightly misleading because it's actually `totalNumberofRowsMinusOne` that ultimately get printed. You might want to adjust this a bit to make the specification clearer, especially if you expose this as a parameter to the caller.

Next, although your code is cleanly written, it's written for compatibility and wouldn't be out of place in a JS codebase 20 years ago. That might be your intent, but now that there are transpilers that handle compatibility for you, you might want to apply modern JS syntax ("ES6") if you wish:

1. Generally avoid loops in favor of functional operations: mapping, filtering, reducing. In this case, we're mapping (transforming a sequence) to build up the rows and then reducing (joining) the rows into a single result. These patterns take some time to recongize, but they're ubiquitous once you start looking for them. Although it doesn't apply here, filtering is when you have `if`s in your loops when you're building your result. It's common to chain these functions in JS.
2. Prefer builtin functions to manipulate strings. Accumulating a string with `+=` in a loop, if I recall correctly, is heavily optimized in Chrome V8, but is normally inefficient, known as [Shlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). Since you've hardcoded the small number 10, it doesn't matter here, but a red flag should rise nonetheless. Accidental, subtle quadratic complexity can be harmful to software trying to scale. We can use `string.repeat(times)` to idiomatically handle the repetition logic.

Here's how I'd write it:

```js
const generatePyramid = rows =>
  [...Array(rows)]
    .map((_, i) => String(i + 1).repeat(i + 1))
    .join("\n")
;
console.log(generatePyramid(9));
```

If you're not familiar with the syntax, I'm using `const` instead of `var`, an arrow function, spread syntax (`...`) on the `Array` constructor to fill in the empty array elements, a `map` function with a callback that accepts an index as the second parameter (which generates the 0...rows values), the abovementioned `string.repeat(n)` to build each row and finally `string.join(delimiter)` to glue the rows together.

Feel free to research these concepts on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) for more information.

Comment: A slightly cuter solution imo since you avoid doing math: `(length) => Array.from({length}, (_, i) => String(i).repeat(i)).filter(s => s).join('\n')`

Comment: I like that idea, but I'd prefer `.slice(1)` to `filter(s => s)` if you're going to make an extra pass over the array. `.slice(1)` more clearly communicates that we're dropping the 0-th element rather than (ab)using the fact that it happens to be falsey, which is rather subtle. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Why are you only printing `rows - 1` rows? I know the original behaves that way, but the original also hard-codes the number. If you're asking for it as a parameter then you've already changed the contract and might as well just honor the value. The consumer can pass in the row count they actually want (or default it to 9 to be truly backwards compatible).

Comment: I agree -- I think I was trying too hard to preserve the number 10, but the caller should pass in 9 if that's what they want. This also obviates the need for the `.slice()` version so I'll remove that. Thanks!

Comment: As some who has bend writing code for 20 years and absolutely hates the newer ES6 junk….I appreciate Kate this answer as you did a really good job explaining some of the newer stuff in a much better way than amy tiutorial or documentation I’ve seen on the subject

Answer (score 1):

The code is very straightforward, but it can be simplified a bit. We can also add a couple of argument validations to the `totalNumberOfRows` to prevent the function from being called incorrectly.

- Ensure that the total number of rows is a number, and is greater than zero.
- Use `string.repeat` to repeat the number in the pyramid instead of a for-loop. This makes the intent clearer.
- Separate side-effects from the function. The function just returns a string, and it's up to the caller what it wants to do with it.
- This code does have a trailing newline. Depending on the application, this might not be preferable.

```
function generatePyramid(totalNumberOfRows) {
  if (!Number.isInteger(totalNumberOfRows)) throw new Error("Total number of rows must be an integer.");
  if (totalNumberOfRows < 0) throw new Error("Total number of rows cannot be less than zero.");

  let output = '';
  for (let i = 1; i < totalNumberOfRows; i++) {
    output += `${i.toString().repeat(i)}\n`;
  }

  return output;
}

console.log(generatePyramid(10));
```

If you're going for code golf (and want a super short version), you could try this:

```
const generatePyramid=e=>[...Array(e).keys()].map(e=>(e+"").repeat(e)).join("\n");
```

In my opinion, the ultra short version begins to lose clarity (but it depends on your preference.)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't very many ways to improve upon your code, but I'll share what I tinkered with to make the code "simpler" and produce the same result.

The first change I made was to use one `console.log` statement and append all parts of the number pyramid to `output`.

The next change uses the [`String.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) method which enabled me to remove the inner loop.

Finally, I extracted `totalNumberOfRows` as a function parameter.

```js
function generatePyramid(totalNumberOfRows) {
  var output = '';
  for (var i = 1; i < totalNumberOfRows; i++) {
    // Since `\n` counts as one character, we need the total length to be `i + 1`
    output += '\n'.padStart(i + 1, i);
  }
  console.log(output);
}
generatePyramid(10);
```